# Powershell regex to split folder path (csv file)

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a list of folder paths in a csv file e.g.

```
\Customer
\Customer\Customer A
\Customer\Customer A\Bob
\Customer\Customer B
\Supplier
"\Supplier\Supplier, A, B"
```

*Note the double quotes*

What I need to do is split each line at the last "\" so the data is then

```
,Customer
\Customer,Customer A
\Customer\Customer A,Bob
\Customer,Customer B
,Supplier
"\Supplier","Supplier, A, B"
```

*Note the double quotes*

I'd like any code to be in powershell if at all possible. I tried using notepad++ by using `(.*)\\`, which selects everything up to and including the last "\", but don't know how to switch that for a ",". This also doesn't help me with the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '\\([^\\]+)$' 

$paths | Foreach-Object {

    if($_ -like '"*"')
    {
        $_ -replace $pattern,'","$1'  
    }
    else
    {
        $_ -replace $pattern,',$1'      
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 I've deleted my answer because I was editing it to manage the double quote making your same solution.

Comment: @Aftab make sure $paths contains only strings. How does your csv file looks like?

Comment: I'm having two issues with the example input above, the only thing I've changed is $path has become import-csv .\test.csv
The following is the output
'@{\Customer=\Customer,Customer A}
@{\Customer=\Customer\Customer A,Bob}
@{\Customer=\Customer,Customer B}
@{\Customer=,Supplier}
@{\Customer=\Supplier,Supplier, A, B}'
1. _\Customer=_ always appears on every line of the output.
2. The first if statement doesn't seem to work because Powershell removes the double quotes from the path value when its imported from csv, how do I changed that behaviour.

Comment: My csv file is exactly like the example I've got the in the question above, that's what I'm using for testing. The original csv file it created using Get-MailboxStatistics in Exchange Management Shell and then I opened it in Excel to delete the second column as I only need the paths.
Also I'm using Powershell ISE to try this code, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: It has no headers so replace $paths with Get-Content file.csv and try again.

Comment: Wow, that works perfect.
I don't understand the headers comment, do you mean column headers?

Comment: Yes, column headers. If the path exists under the Path header then you need to replace $_ with $_.Path

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.LastIndexOf` for finding the split point.  Assuming all you want is a list of strings that include your changes, something like this should work:

```
[String[]] $l = '\Customer',
'\Customer\Customer A',
'\Customer\Customer A\Bob',
'\Customer\Customer B',
'\Supplier',
'"\Supplier\Supplier, A, B"' 

[String[]] $r = @()

foreach ($x in $l)
{
    # work out whether we need to double-quote or not
    if (($x[0] -eq '"') -and ($x[$x.Length - 1] -eq '"'))
    {
        $joiner = '","'
    }
    else
    {
        $joiner = ','
    }

    $i = $x.LastIndexOf('\')
    $s = [String]::Concat($x.Substring(0, $i), $joiner, $x.Substring($i + 1))

    $r = $r + $s
}

$r # contains your output
```